# Django. Filter_vertical change size

Tags: django, django-forms

[image]
I have an issue with a filter_vertical for my model in admin panel. Availble entries has leght about 170 symbols. Standart filter_vertical width is less then I need. It's possible to set new value for width or not and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for my case is override width in .css file

#### App_name/static/css/resize_widget_filter_vertical.css

```
# App_name/static/css/resize_widget_filter_vertical.css
@media (min-width: 1025px)
{
   .change-form .stacked
   {
       width: 890px;
   }

    .change-form .stacked .selector-available,
    .change-form .stacked .selector-chosen,
    .change-form .stacked select
    {
        width: 880px;
    }

   .change-form .stacked .selector-available input
   {
        width: 822px;
   }
}
```

#### admin.py

```
class MyModelName(admin.ModelAdmin)
    ...
    filter_vertical = ('egais_code',)

    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ("css/resize_widget_filter_vertical.css",),
        }
```

and now

[image]